# installing homebrew but something wrong when I run brew doctor

Tags: homebrew

"config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

```
/Users/StevenLee/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/freetype-config
/Users/StevenLee/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python-config
/Users/StevenLee/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python2-config
/Users/StevenLee/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python2.7-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3m-config
```

Warning: Enthought Python was found in your PATH.
This can cause build problems, as this software installs its own
copies of `iconv` and `libxml2` into directories that are picked up by
other build systems.

Warning: Python is installed at */Library/Frameworks/Python.framework*

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to */Library* can interfere
with other software installs.

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in */usr/local/lib*.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:

```
/usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
```

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc
```

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in */usr/local/lib*.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:

```
/usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
/usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a
```